# Is it possible to delete Android app versions in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-console

I am new to Firebase and android. I want to delete a few app versions under ***All app versions*** in Firebase console. Can someone let me know if there is any way to delete specific versions?

The reason is because initially, when I was working with Firebase, I missed the segregate debug and release step. Now all the development triggers are logged into the Firebase.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete the app versions because the firebase analytics has automatic user properties, you can learn about this [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events) and [here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317486?hl=es-419&ref_topic=6317484).

The **solution** is create audience with or without this user properties or directly in panel control select one version from user properties, learn more about this [here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317500?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489).

Tell me if I helps you, greetings!

Comment: Thanks for your response. 

Currently in my Firebase Console I have 6 app versions. In that 6 , only 2 are production build and rest 4 are debug build.

As per your suggestion , I added audience with 2 production build. But when I do next release I need to update the version in audience as well . Is there any other way to do this?